# Umbraco 8.1.5 using .GetMediaInRecycleBin()

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm trying to use the .GetMediaInRecycleBin() method to get a list of all items in the recycle bin.

I've looked through [here](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v7/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Services.IMediaService.html#Umbraco_Core_Services_IMediaService_GetMediaInRecycleBin) and [here](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/management/services/mediaservice/) and can't find any way of doing this in Umbraco 8, the best I have so far is this and this feels like a really bad way of doing it?

```
var mediaService = Current.Services.MediaService;
long pageIndex = 0;
int pageSize = 2147483647; // max int32

var recycled = mediaService.GetPagedMediaInRecycleBin(pageIndex, pageSize, out long totalRecords);
```

It works, but I would really prefer to use the proper method if anyone can help me implement it that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't need to initialise the totalRecords variable. The method will give it to you. Is that not working anyways? Is you want all the records you'll have to iterate on that method.

Comment: @MarioLopez Thanks for the reply, im a little confused as to where your confusion lies? Im trying to get all items in the recycle bin when the user "Emptys the recycle bin" and I cant find another way to get all the media items!